# Can 'where' introduce a specific manner without an antecedent?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, descriptive-grammar, adverbials

I came across this sentence when reading Eclipse, where Sam (werewolf) was the leader of the pack: “ Sam approached Carlisle **where** he stood in the front, the huge pack right on his tail.”

I've known *where* to be of tremendous and versatile use in attributive clauses where it functions to qualify or specify a more generic antecedent as in *We used to do this thing where we would sneak under Alice's bed and wait till it's midnight to scream at her.* In this sentence, the antecedent is the *thing*, *where* introduces an attributive clause to explain what that thing was.

But in *Sam approached Carlisle **where** he stood in the front, the huge pack right on his tail.*, there is no apparent thing to which *where* can be attached to. So can *where* introduce a specific manner/approach/situation/etc. without there being a head noun?
And I assume 'where he stood in the front, the huge pack right on his tail' functions as an adverbial of manner as to how Sam approached Carlisle?

Comment: It seems to me that *where* here is indicating the actual position Carlisle had: at the front. That might be more apparent with a comma after *stood,* but that might be a bit fussy. So it's not an "adverbial of manner" but rather an "adverbial of position". But I don't know how to work such a frame challenge into an answer.

Comment: The preposition "where" prototypically functions as a locative adjunct, often in a 'fused' relative clause, as here, meaning "at the place where he stood ..."

Comment: Ok I get it now. It's like I met him where we used to hang out. I totally let this spiral out of control. It was that simple. Sorry.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112436/discussion-on-question-by-jenny-can-where-introduce-a-specific-manner-without).